# Efficient way of appending Spark DataFrames in a loop using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have '|' delimited huge text files, I want to merge all the text files and create one huge spark dataframe, it will be later used for ETL process, using pyspark.

**Inefficient way**

1) Create an empty spark dataframe, df

2) In a loop,read the text file as to spark dataframe df1 and appending it to empty spark dataframe df

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([],schema)
for x in os.listdir(textfiles_dir):
    filepath = '{}/{}'.format(textfiles_dir,x)
    df1 = spark.read.format("csv") \
                    .option("header", "true") \
                    .option("delimiter", "|") \
                    .option("inferSchema","true") \
                    .load(filepath)
    df = df.union(df1)
```

This is not an efficient spark way.

Can anyone **suggest an efficient way** of doing this?
That would be great if explained with sample code.

Thanks :)

Comment: load the list of paths at once that is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filepath = filepath of directory where multiple files exists

dataframe = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").load(filepath )

Answer (score 0):

1. df1 = spark.read. ... .load("pathFolder/") - read all files with folder
2. df1 save as table db or file

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you will want to read the entire text files directory as a dataframe, rather than iteratively reading each individual directory:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv") \
                    .option("header", "true") \
                    .option("delimiter", "|") \
                    .option("inferSchema","true") \
                    .load(textfiles_dir)
```

If you really want to go the union route, I would recommend using the `union` function in the SparkContext (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=union#pyspark.SparkContext.union) instead of the union function in DataFrame:

```
dfs = []
for x in os.listdir(textfiles_dir):
   filepath = '{}/{}'.format(textfiles_dir,x)
   df1 = spark.read.format("csv") \
                .option("header", "true") \
                .option("delimiter", "|") \
                .option("inferSchema","true") \
                .load(filepath)
   dfs.append(df1)
df = spark.sparkContext.union(dfs)
```